# System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2019-01-03T00:26:01.711-02:00

Tags: apex, datetime

Im trying to format this String into DateTime.

String

> 2019-01-03T00:26:01.711-02:00

Code

```
 String data = '2019-01-03T00:26:01.711-02:00';
 Datetime dt = DateTime.parse(data);
```

Exception

> System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2019-01-03T00:26:01.711-02:00

Comment: Salesforce datetime format is `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Are you trying to achieve timezone?

Comment: Just to add to the confusion a bit, there is at least one place where you would use an ISO 8601 datetime. It's used in SOQL queries like so `[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate > 2019-01-03T00:26:01.711-02:00]` (yes, without quotes surrounding the datetime in this case).

Answer (score 26):

To parse DateTimes in this ISO format, you need to use JSON deserialization.

```
String data = '2019-01-03T00:26:01.711-02:00';
Datetime dt = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + data + '"', DateTime.class);
```

The JSON parser understands ISO format, while `DateTime.parse()` uses the running user's locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

String should be in the local time zone and in the format of the user locale.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_parse

Example:

```
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
String myDtString = dt.format();
system.assertEquals(myDtString, '10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```

[image]