# Invalid date and time error

Tags: apex, datetime, date, conversion, casting

I have a `@restResource` that's receiving a JSON payload as a string. I am taking that payload and placing it into a `Map<String, Object>` variable. I'm trying to save the date/time into a variable that I can later pass to Salesforce.

```
String raw_start_date = (String)response.get('start_date');

Datetime start_date = Datetime.parse(raw_start_date);
```

I keep getting the following error when I receive my test packet:

```
FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2020-01-15T00:00:00Z
```

What am I missing here? I'm I using the wrong command to get the data saved into a `Datetime` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247210/system-typeexception-invalid-date-time-2019-01-03t002601-711-0200) is asking a similar question.

To quote from that answer:

'To parse DateTimes in ISO format, you need to use JSON deserialization. The JSON parser understands ISO format, while `DateTime.parse()` uses the running user's locale settings.'

You'll want to use something like:

`Datetime dt = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + raw_start_date + '"', DateTime.class);`

Comment: I tried that exact example an hour ago and it didn't work. For whatever reason it works now. Not even going to question it. Thank you